# CoreData UIKit SwiftUI

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui

I'm just learning about `CoreData` for Swift. I've managed to successfully get it working in SwiftUI but unable to get it working in a `UIKit` SwiftUI based app using the same method. The toggle state is retained and working in the pure SwiftUI based app so I assumed I could do something  similar in the `UIKit` based SwiftUI app but the toggle state never changes in the `UIKit` SwiftUI app.

I'm using the same entities in both projects, attribute name, boolean value, and set the default value. My question is can I not use the same code from the pure SwiftUI app in the `UIKit` based SwiftUI app?

```swift
import CoreData

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Item.isOn, ascending: true)], animation: .default)
    private var items: FetchedResults<Item>
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Toggle("", isOn: Binding<Bool>(
                get: { items.first?.isOn ?? true},
                set: {
                    items.first?.isOn = $0
                    try? viewContext.save()
                    print("value: \($0)")
                }
            ))
            .labelsHidden()
            .frame(width: 100, height: 100, alignment: .center)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe it could also help clarifying if you post the code both of your `AppDelegate` (from the UIKit version), and your `@main struct` (from your pure SwiftUI) to see what might be missing from the initialisation.

Comment: And also maybe you would prefer to refer to them as: 'SwiftUI app lifecycle', and 'SwiftUI with UIKit app lifecycle', these may be more commonly used terms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what do you mean by "UIKit based SwiftUI app", but looking at your code first thought is:

Do you have any `Item` object? I don't see code where you create it, and if there's no one - your setter will do nothing.

Another thing that you may forget, is settings `.environment(\.managedObjectContext, context)` for your root SwiftUI view in your `SceneDelegate`, or whenever you're initialising it with `UIHostingController`

And ofc you `AppDelegate` should've `persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer`, but you probably have it if you've created an app with CoreData.

Comment: SwiftUI with AppDelegate, pure SwiftUI without AppDelegate is working fine. So I don't see the difference as to why it's not working. Items are created via CoreData `.xcdatamodeld`

Comment: @cole `.xcdatamodeld` only creates a class for an item, I'm talking about initialising an instance and saving it to the context

Comment: In the SwiftUI app I set it in my `PersistenceController` `let newItem = Item(context: viewContext) newItem.isOn = true`. But that may be the problem, I'm not to sure where to initialize it in my AppDelegate or? I just noticed that I didn't set it

Comment: @cole not sure what're you looking for, but you can try do it in the `AppDelegate` Just don't forget that it'll be called on each app launch so you probably need to make sure wasn't not yet created or you'll get a lot of items in your database one day.

Comment: you were right, I added it in my `SceneDelegate` and it's working. Just adding `let newItem = Item(context: context)` and `newItem.isOn = true` in `scene(_:willConnectTo:options:)`.